# Cropped pdf file after export

Tags: export, pdf-format

I have plot generated by `Plot[]` function that I want to export to pdf file. The problem is that `Export[]` function somehow cuts a tiny bit of plot on the left side which results in something like this:
[image: Exported image]

I'd like to know what should I do to get exported file without cropped $0$.

Comment: It's always best if you provide an example of the code you used. But even without that, I would suggest manually setting the `Plot` option `ImagePadding -> 70` (or use a larger number).

Comment: @Jens thanks, that works good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my original suggestion using `ImagePadding`:

```
p = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.1], 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}, TicksStyle -> Large, RotateLabel -> False, 
  ImagePadding -> 70]
```

[image: imagemargins]

And here is an example of how to use `ImageMargins` in the plot command:

```
p = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.1], 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}, TicksStyle -> Large, RotateLabel -> False, 
  ImageMargins -> 70]
```

Both methods work to give you extra space around the image. But I see Mr. Wizard just now explained this already.

**Edit: a note for completeness**

In a [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7453/245), one can see that neither `ImagePadding` nor `ImageMargins` work in some situations. Here is an example where `Epilog` is used to place a text below a plot:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> {Text["Show me the text", {Pi, -1.3}]}]
```

The text is *not* shown because it falls outside the `PlotRange`. When this happens, you can fix the problem by using `PlotRangePadding`:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> {Text["Show me the text", {Pi, -1.3}]}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> .5]
```

[image: plot with epilog]

Comment: I reduced my answer to this after realizing I was confusing `ImagePadding` and `ImageMargins`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Now you confuse me because I was editing while you were too... Hopefully all the bases are covered now.

Comment: Jens, sorry, if I had been thinking clearly about `ImageMargins`/`ImagPadding` from the start I would have not have had to make a series of edits.

Comment: That's OK - you got my +1.

Answer (score 10):

Please try adding some space around the plot:

```
Plot[2 Sin[x] + x, {x, 0, 15}, Filling -> Bottom, ImageMargins -> 10]
```

`ImageMargins` gives a margin around the existing plot that can be seen by selecting the graphic (the outer orange frame):

[image]

By comparison `ImagePadding` is used by `Plot` itself to make room for the axes labels (the inner orange frame).

Comment: Thanks, but proposed `ImagePadding` option works good and is sufficient for my needs.

Comment: @qoqosz actually I didn't see that comment above, and also I was confusing ImageMargins with ImagePadding; you *can* use `ImageMargins` directly in `Plot` and that would be a good method because you can use a small fixed value without cutting of the labels, as you would with `ImagePadding`.

Comment: Ok, good to know :)