# X label in GraphicsColumn is cut off 

Tags: plotting, graphics, options, labeling

I'm trying to use GraphicsColumn to plot two curves with very different ranges. for example,

```
GraphicsColumn[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AspectRatio -> 0.3, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   ImageMargins -> 20], 
  Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 0.3, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageMargins -> 20]}, 
 Epilog -> {Text["Frequency", {Center, Bottom}], 
   Rotate[Text["Power", {0.5, Center}], 90 Degree]}]
```

But the x label is not displayed properly, i.e., it is cut by the edge of the graph.

[image]

How to improve it?

Comment: A related question is: [Cropped pdf file after export](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7237/245)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`PlotRangePadding` option can give you more space around your graphics objects.

```
GraphicsColumn[{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AspectRatio -> 0.3, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   ImageMargins -> 20], 
  Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 0.3, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageMargins -> 20]}, Epilog -> 
  Style[{Text["Frequency", Scaled@{.5, .02}], 
    Rotate[Text["Power", Scaled@{.03, .5}], 90 Degree]}, 14, 
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], PlotRangePadding -> {0, 70}, 
 ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. You've known so much about plot!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Just checked. Image corresponds to the code. M.8.0.4, win7.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Maybe something changed for absolute coordinate specs from v7 to v8. I changed code to scaled coordinates. Could you check if this helps?

Comment: Confirmed to work. +1

Answer (score 6):

An alternative using `Labeled`:

```
Labeled[
 GraphicsColumn[{
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 0.3,
    Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageMargins -> 0], 
   Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 0.3, 
    Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageMargins -> 0]}, 
   Alignment -> Left], 
 {"Frequency", "Power"}, {Bottom, Left}, 
 RotateLabel -> True, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
 FrameMargins -> 0, ImageMargins -> 10]
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer this one！