# Cropped FrameLabel - how to fix?

Tags: plotting

Consider

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> Scaled[0.05]], Style["sin(x)", FontSize -> Scaled[0.05]]}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Scaled[0.02]]
```

[image]

The label $\sin(x)$ is cropped from the left. Adding `PlotRangePadding -> {0, .5}` as a brutal fix seems to work:

[image]

but it obviously alters the plot range as it is intended to do. This can't be circumvented with `PlotRange` as it's overwriten.

How to prevent the cropping?

Comment: Related: [(7453)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7453/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Framed` around the problematic piece.  **Update:**  It seems you can also use `Pane` (see comments).

`Framed` is not only for drawing frames. It is also for controlling the box that contains the expression.  You can eliminate the border with `FrameStyle -> None`.  Other relevant options are `ContentPadding` and `FrameMargins`. Note that in the latter, negative values are allowed too, which will let you effectively control the box placement (move it closer to the graphics frame).

However, if your aim is to scale graphics proportionally, I recommend using `Magnify` instead of making all units scaled.

Comment: So maybe `Pane` to not care about options.

Comment: @Kuba Hm, good point ... I cannot see what may go wrong with `Pane`.  I have always used `Framed` for such things. As I remember, some builtin stuff also uses it (well, `FrameBox` to be precise). SciDraw makes heavy use of `Framed` too, for this very purpose.  So it is proven to work.  I will try using `PaneBox` in the future to discover if it has any problems.