# How to write on an added margins in a plot?

Tags: plotting, writing

I added margin to a plot and I am trying to use `Epilog` to write a comment inside the margin but it did not work?  How can I writ inside the added margin without using the `Drawing Tools`

```
Plot[{x}, {x, 0, 3}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 3}, 
  ImageMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 50}}, 
  Epilog -> {Text[Style["m=0", {FontSize -> 18, Black, 
    FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}], Scaled[{.14, 1}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: do you get what you want if you add the option `PlotRangeClipping -> False`?

Comment: @kglr No, it did not give the desired result

Comment: perhaps [`PlotRangePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangePadding.html) is helpful

Comment: Somewhat related: [(140710)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140710/cropped-framelabel-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the options `PlotRangeClipping` and `ImagePadding`:

```
Plot[{x}, {x, 0, 3}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 3}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 50}}, 
 Epilog -> {Text[Style["m=0", {FontSize -> 18, Black, 
      FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"}], Scaled[{.14, 1.1}]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Without `PlotRangeClipping->False` and using `FrameLabel` if you want to display the text as title:

```
Plot[{x}, {x, 0, 3}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 3}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 30}}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"y", ""}, 
   {"x", Text[Style["m=0", 20, Red, FontFamily -> "Times"]]}}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18, Black, FontFamily -> "Arial"}]
```

[image]