# Stop cutting a long text in label

Tags: plotting, labeling, padding

In

```
ListLinePlot[{RandomReal[4, 6], RandomReal[2, 8], RandomReal[10, 12]},
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(N\), \(b\)]\) de sièges", 
   "Sièges parSyndicat"}, PlotLabels -> {"FO", "SM", "SdM"}]
```

how can we guarantee that the Axes Label

```
{"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(N\), \(b\)]\) de sièges",    "Sièges parSyndicat"}
```

is not cut like in this example:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

### Using [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html)

```
ListLinePlot[
 {
  RandomReal[4, 6],
  RandomReal[2, 8],
  RandomReal[10, 12]
  }
 , ImagePadding -> Full
 , AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(N\), \(b\)]\) de sièges", "Sièges parSyndicat"}
 , PlotLabels -> {"FO", "SM", "SdM"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Using [`FrameLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameLabel.html)

```
ListLinePlot[
 {
  RandomReal[4, 6],
  RandomReal[2, 8],
  RandomReal[10, 12]
  }
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(N\), \(b\)]\) de sièges", "Sièges parSyndicat"}
 , PlotLabels -> {"FO", "SM", "SdM"}
 ]
```

[image]

---

You should also see the solutions to [this other question (7453)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7453/10397) .
Have a look  into the documentation of

- [`ImageMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMargins.html)
- [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html)
- [`PlotRangePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangePadding.html)

---

<sub>All plots were created using *Mathematica 11.1.1* On Windows 7.</sub>

Comment: for me PlotLabels doesn't work. Did you load a Package to get the Labels? I'm only familiar with PlotLabel, which is doing something different.

Comment: @RMMA `PlotLabels` was introduced in *Mathematica v 10.4*, which version do you have? I did NOT use any packages.

Comment: ok. I'm using 10.3. PlotLabels seems to be useful.